# JQuery - animate a div left

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm working on a website that should support JQuery Animations,
I want to animate the menu items such that each menu item should move to right if the mouse hovers on it,

I searched the web and found the required animate scripts, but they didn't work,

can anyone help me please?

here's the peace of code that I have:

```
$('.menuButton').hover(
            function () { $(this).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow"); },
            function () { $(this).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow"); }
        );
```

it's already in the document.ready(..)

I hope I find my answer,
thanks.

Comment: Make sure that menuButton is absolutely positioned. Also, show your markup and CSS with http://jsfiddle.net/, so that we can better help you.

Comment: The current code works fine. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.7.1.min,

Here's the HTML Code,,

<div id="leftArea">
                <div class="menuButton" id="merchandiseButton"></div>
                <div class="menuButton" id="Div2"></div>
                <div class="menuButton" id="Div3"></div>
                <div class="menuButton" id="Div1"></div>
</div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/GH5BJ/. Or `position : relative` works but `position : absolute` is the best for performance (and it really makes a big difference). Be careful that you are moving the element away from the cursor which can cause an infinite loop of events to trigger.

Comment: I set the position into relative and that worked just fine,
thanks for your hint :)

Answer (score 0):

the second animation should be a passed as callback.

```
    $('.menuButton').hover(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow", function() {
            $this.animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank You, the div should be positioned relative as Japser replied, thank you